# Windows Indentity Foundation on Win 8

Tags: windows-8, wif

I’ve followed [this discussion on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001598/911182) and went to [Windows Identity Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331), as advised, to download WIF. The best match for my OS is Win 8, so I downloaded the file, `Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu`. This has worked so far with drivers and such, so it was worth a shot.

However, as I start the installation process the computer complains about encountered error 0x80096002: “The certificate for the signer of the message is invalid or not found”.

Does it have to do with wrong version of OS? How can I dance around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WIF has been integrated in the OS on Net 4.5 under System.IdentityModel and System.IdentityModel.Services dlls. No need to download anything else.

More details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2012/03/15/windows-identity-foundation-in-the-net-framework-4-5-beta-tools-samples-claims-everywhere.aspx

Comment: Is that so? I googled the subject and found nothing of the kind. Was I temporarily retarded or is it a change that isn't so big a deal that MS would mention it somewhere? I'll try that out at work tomorrow and if it flies, I'll sure grade your reply as an answer. Surprised that no one asked that question before. .Net4.5 has been around for a while, now...

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that it's an indirect consequence. NET 4.5 is included on Windows 8 by default. And NET 4.5 includes System.IdentityModel so if you look for Windows 8 and WIF there are two levels of indirections. Added a link to a blog from someone at Microsoft from March.

Comment: I can't find it in the system. Perhaps I'm looking for it the wrong way. I went to "References", right-clicked on "Add Reference" and searched in all of the ".NET", "COM" etc. No Microsoft.IdentityModel to be found... What can I do about it? I'm assuming that .NET Framework 4.5 is installed because I run Win8 and VS2010...

Comment: I just noticed something weird. When I go into project settings, I can only choose .NET Frameworks up to 4.0 (i.e. there's no 4.5 in the list to be picked). So I headed and downloaded *dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe* [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sv-se/download/details.aspx?id=30653). But then, I get [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/sv-se/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30653) with information that I already got it. I even tried to install it despite it but only got a message box telling me to buzz off for the same reason. So *have* I got .NET4.5 or not?!

Comment: I just found [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vssetup/thread/8ab8782d-36f5-4b7a-a264-c68f2dd564f9) where a guy claims that .NET 4.5 isn't supported by VS2010. WTF?! Why on Earth isn't it supported? I **REALLY**, **REALLY** don't want to install the rectum-ugly atrocity to IDE called VS12... Really don't...

Answer (score 2):

This one fixed it for me today...

http://www.stratospher.es/blog/post/installing-windows-identity-foundation-on-windows-8-the-certificate-for-the-signer-of-the-message-is-invalid-or-not-found

The one issue I found in the instructions is that on step #3 it says "Windows Identity Framework 3.5", when on my machine it says "Windows Identity Foundation 3.5".

Other than that it worked like a charm.