# Microsoft.IdentityModel in Window XP

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

We have Window XP where Outlook for CRM-11 is installed.

I developed a Outlook Addin and installed on this system.

Setup could not be installed due to "Microsoft.IdentityModel" is not found as it does not support in XP.

Then how Outlook(With CRM) is installed in this system??

Do we have any alternate solution for this to be work in XP?

Any help will will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the Microsoft.IdentityModel dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001598/where-is-the-microsoft-identitymodel-dll)

Comment: Mainly i am asking about Outlook Connector with CRM and alternate way for IdentityModel in XP.

Though i know where this is installed but what is alternate way to solve this in XP.

Answer (score 1):

The outlook client doesn't require Windows Identity Foundation to run but any ISV development against the Organization Service does i.e your Add-in.

There's nothing stopping you from installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll to the GAC on the client XP machines but this is an unsupported solution both in terms of the desktop build and CRM 2011.  The alternative is to rewrite your add-in to use the WSDL based CRM service instead or upgrade the client OS!  I appreciate the latter is unlikely hence your question.

Comment: Later is perfect..but it is not under my control..:)


First one is using WSDL service? I used service that is normally got from CrmOrganizationService Object..

No knowledge that how to get WSDL service for CRUD Operation from Online CRM Database.