# Not able to find Windows.IdentityModel for windows 10 store app development

Tags: active-directory, windows-store-apps, windows-identity

Is this dll not compatible with windows store app, Or is there any other way to achieve the same.

I tried adding it from nuget package also but not happening, I am getting this error:

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Solution'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, you need to intall the [Windows Identity Foundation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331) as well as the [WIF SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4451) and then restart the application for the effect to work.

For Windows 10 device, Windows Identity foundation is not an istall but a Windows feature need to be enabled.

- Enter Control Panel from Start menu
- Click program and features
- Choose turn Windows feature on or off
- Choose Winodws Identity Framework, click OK
- Restart your machine

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001598/where-is-the-microsoft-identitymodel-dll) that could be helpful to you. As Moory said in the comment, he fixed this issue by adding the reference below to the csproj file:: ( .

Please also try it. Thank you.